# Call function from ascx to .cs of a user control and draw html

Tags: ascx

I have a user control, I want to make if conditions in the ascx, and upon that call a function in the user control and return data from the method to be displayed as html in the ascx. Any ideas? I am still newbie to asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop a literal onto your user control. Then in your code behind, it'll look something like this:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Make your IF conditions here

    MyFunction();
}

private void MyFunction()
{
    string myHtml = "<div>My Html Code!</div>";

    literal1.Text = myHtml;
}
```

That should render your HTML.